# What is the best strategy for web application to create temporary .csv files?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, server, temporary-files

My application would create .csv files temporarily for storing some data rows. What is the best strategy to manage this kind of temporary files creation and delete them after user logs out of the app? 
I think creating temporary .csv files on the server isn't good idea. 
Is there any simple way to manage temporary file creation at client machine (browser)?

These .csv files contains table records -> which would be used as source later for d3.js visualization charts/elements.

Please share your experience on real time applications for this scenario ?

I'm using DJango framework (Python) for doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Why create on-disk files **at all**? For smaller files, use an in-memory file object like [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

If your CSV file sizes can potentially get large, use a [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile); these dynamically swap out data to a on-disk file if you write enough data to them. Once closed, the file is cleared from disk automatically.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Thanks for the suggestion! I'm going through tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(). Looks like this does exactly what I wanted to. But the problem is I cannot refer to it in d3.js script :(. Python is underlying code, but I need to refer the file object in javascript code of my html.

Comment: @user3128771: you cannot refer to files on a remote HTTP server in a `d3.js` script either. You still need to send the result to the client once the data is built.

Comment: @user3128771: `d3.js` takes a *URL* for the CSV file; your view produces a CSV response (which doesn't have to be a physical file at all).

Comment: I cannot use StringIO or any string object to store the rows which were fetched from the table.. Reason being, I have to do lot of conversions to get as per my desired format. if it is any temporary file with some extension, I can store the records in any character delimited fashion and I can later use it directly without performing changes. Otherwise, I would end up with lot of changes on the fetched records. - (Rows to Arrays - JSON - Arrays converted to Json in python changes for some reason in Javascript...)

Comment: @user3128771: then I'll have to give up here, as it sounds like you have a whole pile of problems to solve. That's too broad for comments or one Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thats right. I'm trying hard to find out if there is any other best way to do d3 js visualization using python's DJango framework. .. Or may be I need to explore python's packages for visualization.

Answer (score 0):

If your preference is to store the data client side, ["HTML local storage"](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#localstorage) could be an option for you. This lets you store string data in key value pairs in the user's browser subject to a same origin policy (so data for one origin (domain) is visible only to that origin). There is also a 5MB limit on data size which must be strings - OK for CSV.

Provided that your visualisation pages/code is served from the same domain, the data in local storage will be accessible to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mhawke! I would go through it now.